# How to turn off highlight of first mat-radio-button in mat radio group

Tags: css, angular, typescript, hover

I created component with form.
Every answers group is different mat-radio-group (will be easier to see it in code below):

```
<mat-list>
  <div *ngFor="let q of qs">
    <mat-list-item>
      ...content of question...
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-list-item>
      <mat-radio-group name="{{q.name}}" [formControlName]=q.fieldName ngDefaultControl>
        <span>
            <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let answer of q.answers" value="{{answer}}">{{answer}}</mat-radio-button>
        </span>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </mat-list-item>
  </div>
</mat-list>
```

Form and buttons are working very well but I get some problem with first radio button on page.
The first one button in first group, and only that one, has something like auto hover on start (check preview image). It will dissapear after click somewhere but it is irritating to see this on start.

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQA8G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Oh... so problem solved...
The reason of that hover were not in mat-radio-group.
I had to add:

```
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(component, {
    ....
     autoFocus: false
   });
```

in component where I call dialogWindow